# Connection to one from two Identical databases in Spring boot application at RUNTIME

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, datasource, multiple-databases, spring-config

### UPDATED

I'm getting an issue with Spring framework while I try to connect to 2 identical databases (with same tables) and then choose one of them to make requests. I'm using for this, 3 config files ***DbConfig***, **AbstractRoutingDataSource** and an **application.properties** file.
I'm currently not getting any ERRORS, while starting my application, but any time I use my restful webservice I get empty data, check the controller file below.

NOTE: I've followed all these links and still no results:

1. [Baeldung AbstractRoutingDataSource guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source)
2. [Alexander guide](http://fedulov.website/2015/10/14/dynamic-datasource-routing-with-spring/)
3. [Dynamic DataSource Routing on Spring website](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)

I'm working on Spring boot v2.0.5.

**NOTE: please do NOT answer me if you don't have any ideas about AbstractRoutingDataSource class and how it works.**

### My application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

# Main database DEV_database1 
first.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DEV_database1 
first.datasource.username = root 
first.datasource.password =  
first.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# second database DEV_database2 
second.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DEV_database2 
second.datasource.username = root 
second.datasource.password =  
second.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
#...
```

### [UPDATE] My DbConfig file

```
@Configuration
public class DbConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("first.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public HikariDataSource firstDataSource() {
        return firstDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("second.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties secondDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public HikariDataSource secondDataSource() {
        return secondDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }   

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSources() {

        AbstractRoutingDataSource dataSource = new CustomerRoutingDataSource();

        Map<Object, Object> resolvedDataSources = new HashMap<>();    
        resolvedDataSources.put(DbType.DATASOURCE1, firstDataSource());
        resolvedDataSources.put(DbType.DATASOURCE2, secondDataSource());

        dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(firstDataSource()); // << default
        dataSource.setTargetDataSources(resolvedDataSources);
        return dataSource;
    }   
}
```

### My CustomerRoutingDataSource.java

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;
/**
 * AbstractRoutingDatasource can be used in place of standard DataSource implementations and enables a mechanism to
 * determine which concrete DataSource to use for each operation at runtime.
 * 
 * @author fre
 */
public class CustomerRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerRoutingDataSource.class);

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        log.info(">>> determineCurrentLookupKey thread: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName() );
        log.info(">>> RoutingDataSource: {}", DbContextHolder.getDbType());
        return DbContextHolder.getDbType();
    }
}
```

### My DbContextHolder.java

```
public class DbContextHolder {

       private static final ThreadLocal<DbType> contextHolder =
                new ThreadLocal<DbType>();
       // set the datasource
       public static void setDbType(DbType dbType) {
           if(dbType == null){
               throw new NullPointerException();
           }
          contextHolder.set(dbType);
       }
       // get the current datasource in use
       public static DbType getDbType() {
          return (DbType) contextHolder.get();
       }
       // clear datasource
       public static void clearDbType() {
          contextHolder.remove();
       }
}
```

### DbType.java

```
public enum DbType {
    DATASOURCE1, 
    DATASOURCE2,
}
```

This is how I'm using it in Controller:

### My Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class MembreController extends MainController {

    @Autowired
    MembreRepository membreRepository;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public ResponseString login(String userName, String password) {

        // setting the datasouce to DATASOURCE1
        DbContextHolder.setDbType(DbType.DATASOURCE1);

        // finding the list of user in DataSource1
        List<Membres> list = membreRepository.findAll();

        // clearing the current datasource
        DbContextHolder.clearDbType();

        for (Iterator<Membres> membreIter = list.iterator(); membreIter.hasNext();) {
            Membres membre = membreIter.next();

            if (membre.getUserName().equals(userName) && membre.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                return new ResponseString("Welcome" + membre.getFirstName() + " " + membre.getLastName());
            }
        }
        return new ResponseString("User not found");
    }

}
```

### my Application.java file

```
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    /**
     * main method
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: What isn't working? What error do you get? Also you are using Spring Boot then how are you loading that XML configuration file. Looks like you are mixing things you shouldn't be mixing (or at least mixing them in the wrong way).

Comment: I'm not getting any error actually, do you propose me to change my config in the xml file into a java file?

Comment: No I'm wondering why you are using XML and Spring Boot. I also suspect that that  is part of your problem by (re)defining things instead of using Spring Boot. Also I would suggest to add `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` to your properties, if you don't an `Entitymanager` and `Connection` are opened very early before you have time to set the correct value for the `AbstractRoutingDataSource`. also remove the loading of the `application.properties` from your xml as that should be handled by Spring Boot already. Also your `spring.jpa` properties are of no use as you are configuring JPA yourself.

Comment: ok what about the appContext.xml file? do I have to delete it ?

Comment: I did what you told me and nothing has been changed :(

Comment: You haven't shown, the full picture, I had questions and requests you didn't answer. Show your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. Show your full configuration. You are trying to work around Spring Boot, which as I stated ,I suspect is part of your problem. As well as the `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` which opens a DB connection before you can switch it. Doing `DbContextHolder.setDbType(DbType.DATASOURCE1);` should be done very early, in a filter before anything else. If you don't you will re-use the pre-bound session and connection.

Comment: I've added my config file DbConfig, and application file, please check what I'm I missing, also, I've noticed, after calling the webservice in my controller that one of the database is responding, but unfortunately not the one specified in the DbContextHolder.set() method. also no errors!

Comment: Your `AbstractRoutingDataSource` should be the `@Primary`. Also disable the open-entity-manager-in-view as stated earlier.

Comment: I'm getting an error after marking `AbstractRoutingDataSource` as `@Primary`, the error is in the console:
APPLICATION FAILED TO START  Parameter 1 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker required a single bean, but 3 were found:

Comment: It says:
Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using `@Qualifier` to identify the bean that should be consumed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found the solution!
The problem was simply with my .properties and my DbConfig files. I just omitted databases parameters from .properties file and added them manually to my DbConfig file. and it works fine:

### My Properties file

```
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
#...
```

### My DbConfig

```
   @Configuration
public class DbConfig{

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "dataSource1")
    DataSource dataSource1() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DEV_database1?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull")
                .driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").username("root").password("").build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource2")
    DataSource dataSource2() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database2")
                .driverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").username("root").password("").build();
    }

    @Primary    
    @Bean(name = "mainDataSource")
    DataSource dataSources() {

        AbstractRoutingDataSource dataSource = new CustomerRoutingDataSource();
        DataSource dataSource1= dataSource1();
        DataSource dataSource2 = dataSource2();
        Map<Object, Object> resolvedDataSources = new HashMap<>();
        resolvedDataSources.put(DbType.DATASOURCE1, dataSource1);
        resolvedDataSources.put(DbType.DATASOURCE2, dataSource2 );
        dataSource.setTargetDataSources(resolvedDataSources);
        dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSource1); // << default
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

**THATS NOT ALL!** I got a new error after this! it says:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration
┌─────┐
|  dataSource defined in class path resource [tn/fre/gestdoc/DbConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  dataSource1 defined in class path resource [tn/fre/gestdoc/DbConfig.class]
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker
└─────┘
```

I followed this: [Answer on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6987#issuecomment-407369314) and the error has gone, the application works fine now!! I can choose which datasource from my login controller, thanks [@M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum)